# Store belongsToMany relationships w/ Conditions - Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following tables for my many to many relationship: `soldhomestests`, `tasks` and `soldhomestest_task` (as the pivot).

My soldhomestests table has already been populated with data. How do I get my soldhomestest_task pivot table to populate with data upon the creation of a new task that meets conditions in my soldhomestest table? In my example, I want to store the relationship data when the following conditions are met:

```
'tasks.city' = 'soldhomestests.city'
'tasks.address' = 'soldhomestests.address'
```

I can't seem to find any documentation on how to proceed with this?

**MODELS:**

```
class Task extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'address', 'city', 'state',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function soldhomestests()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Soldhomestest');
    }
}

class Soldhomestest extends Model
{

    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Task');
    }
}
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'address' => 'required|max:255',
            'city' => 'required|max:255',
            'state' => 'required|max:255',
        ]);

        $request->user()->tasks()->create([
            'address' => $request->address,
            'city' => $request->city,
            'state' => $request->state,
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('settings.index');
    }
```

Comment: You could use Eloquent events. https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#events

Answer (score 0):

Don't believe this is the Laravel way but I modified my controller to create an array of IDs using the where condition:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'address' => 'required|max:255',
            'city' => 'required|max:255',
            'state' => 'required|max:255',
        ]);

        $newtask = $request->user()->tasks()->create([
            'address' => $request->address,
            'city' => $request->city,
            'state' => $request->state,
        ]);

        $condition = DB::table('soldhomestests')->where([
            ['soldhomestests.address', '=', $request->address],
            ['soldhomestests.city', '=', $request->city],
          ])->pluck('id');

        $lastid = $newtask->id;
        $tasksoldhome = Task::find($lastid);
        $tasksoldhome->soldhomestests()->sync($condition);

        return redirect()->route('settings.index');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using eloquent, you can do this way.

```
$task=new Task();
$task->city=$request->city;
$task->address=$request->address;
$task->save();

$soldhometests=Soldhometest::all();
foreach($soldhometests as $soldhometest)
{
    if($task->city==$soldhometest->city && $task->address==$soldhometest->address)
    {     
          $soldhometest_task=new SoldhometestTask();  // pivot model
          $soldhometest_task->task_id=$task->id;
          $soldhometest_task->soldhometest_id=$soldhometest->id;
          $soldhometest_task->save();
     }
}
```